# ODataAngularResources not parse OData 4 response

Tags: angularjs, typescript, odata, ngresource

I try call OData v4 service with [ODataAngularResources](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources) from typescript.

For test purpose I use [Northwind Products OData Service](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products)

Here is code wich call service:

```
var results = this.$odataresource("http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products")
                        .odata()
                        .filter("UnitPrice", ">", 10)
                        .filter("Discontinued", true)
                        .take(2)
                        .query();
```

**Request URL** :http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=(UnitPrice%20gt%2010)%20and%20(Discontinued%20eq%20true)&$top=2

**Response :**

```
{     "@odata.context":"http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products",
       "value":[  
          {  
             "ProductID":5,
             "ProductName":"Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
             "SupplierID":2,
             "CategoryID":2,
             "QuantityPerUnit":"36 boxes",
             "UnitPrice":21.3500,
             "UnitsInStock":0,
             "UnitsOnOrder":0,
             "ReorderLevel":0,
             "Discontinued":true
          },
          {  
             "ProductID":9,
             "ProductName":"Mishi Kobe Niku",
             "SupplierID":4,
             "CategoryID":6,
             "QuantityPerUnit":"18 - 500 g pkgs.",
             "UnitPrice":97.0000,
             "UnitsInStock":29,
             "UnitsOnOrder":0,
             "ReorderLevel":0,
             "Discontinued":true
          }
       ]
    }
```

**Deserialized response:**

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
0: Resource
1: Resource
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
@odata.context: "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata#Products"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I would like have deserialized response as array of Product object.

I really dont’t know where can be problem.

In app I use ODataResources but also ngResource.